# How to use two traits with enum_dispatch?

Tags: rust, enums, dispatch, enum-dispatch

I've tried:

```
#[enum_dispatch(BarTrait, BazTrait)]
pub enum Foo {
    VariantZero,
    ...
}
```

It seems to ignore any traits after the first, silently.

This causes errors, as in this case the compiler doesn't seem to believe that Foo implements BazTrait.

---

Update: @kmdreko's [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b60f1386df38cbd080ec89b3c426a6d9) works properly so long as `BazTrait` is in the same crate as `Foo`.

When `BazTrait` is in a different crate, which also uses `enum_dispatch`, `BazTrait` is ignored and causes two errors of the form:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `baz` found for enum `Foo` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:53:9
   |
45 | enum Foo {
   | -------- method `baz` not found for this
...
53 |     foo.baz();
   |         ^^^ method not found in `Foo`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `baz`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `mylib::BazTrait`
```

It is important to note that there is no error at either `#[enum_dispatch(BarTrait, BazTrait)]` or `pub enum Foo {`.

Comment: Can you make a more complete example? [This code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b60f1386df38cbd080ec89b3c426a6d9) seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I'll post a more complete example in the morning.  I didn't know whether `enum_dispatch` was even meant to work with multiple traits, so thanks for confirming.

Comment: I can confirm that your code works fine, when it's all in the same crate.  I've updated the question with new observations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#[enum_dispatch]` attribute does not work across crates:

> Unfortunately, procedural macros in Rust are limited in a few ways that will make what you're trying to achieve impossible - notably, they are run independently *per-crate*, so there's no way for information from one crate to affect an implementation in another.

<sup>*From the author of enum_dispatch in an [unrelated issue](https://gitlab.com/antonok/enum_dispatch/-/issues/22).*</sup>